# Reducing the perimeter of a plane without reducing area??

Tags: geometry

There is rectangle pool with an area of 36 square-yards, then there is another pool of the same area, but with a smaller perimeter. How is this achieved?

Comment: How would you fit more area into a smaller perimeter?

Comment: That's what I'm wondering! This question comes from my little sisters summer homework, I think there was a mistake.

Comment: Think squarish.

Comment: Just find two rectangles with the required area, then you can work out which has the bigger perimeter and which the smaller.

Comment: What if the rectangular pool is already a square? Think round, to be safe. (Though for homework, they probably wanted the answer to be a square).

Comment: How about a circular  pool with radius $r=\dfrac{6}{\sqrt{\pi}}$. Then we have perimeter $$S=12\sqrt{\pi}\approx21.26944621$$ This perimeter is less than any rectangular perimeter.

Answer (score 2):

A pool with length and width of $6$ and $6$ has area $36$.

Another of length and width $4$ and $9$ has area $36$.

However, the former has perimeter $24$, whereas the latter has perimeter $26$.